# Get variables from different controllers in Silex 2

Tags: silex

Making first project on Silex 2. 
Don't know how to make a variable from one controller available for other controller.

```
$app -> get('links', function() use ($app) {
$foo="foo";
})
->bind('a1');   


$app -> get ('/links/result/', function() use ($app) {
echo $foo;
})
->bind('b2');
```

How to make $foo visible for "b2"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to do something in two controllers, best make it a service; then it's available in both. [Here's the Silex docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/services.html) on service creation.

You'll need to create a class first:

```
class MyFirstService
{
    public function getFoo()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Then register it as a (shared) service:

```
$app["my-first-service"] = $app->share(function () { 
    return new MyFirstService();
});
```

Finally you can use it:

```
$app->get('links', function() use ($app) {
    $foo = $app["my-first-service"]->getFoo();
})->bind('a1');   

$app->get ('/links/result/', function() use ($app) {
    $foo = $app["my-first-service"]->getFoo();
})->bind('b2');
```

The above linked documentation page also tells how you can access other services in yours.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using:
`function() use ($app) {`
in controller closures - you can use $app as a global variable container like:
`$app['my_vars']['foo']='bar';`

In a perfect way you should use data modal class for a variable storage.